# Where are syscalls located in glibc source

Tags: c, linux, glibc

So I was looking through the linux glibc source and I don't see where it actually does anything.  The following is from `io/chdir.c` but it is indicative of many of the source files.  What's going on here?  Obviously I am missing something.  What's the secret, where does it make a system call or actually do something?

`stub_warning` is some legacy craziness.  `__set_errno` seems to be a simple macro that sets `errno`.  And while I find a million usages of `weak_alias` I don't see it defined anywhere.

Is there a helpful guide to understanding how glibc works somewhere?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Change the current directory to PATH.  */
int
__chdir (path)
     const char *path;
{
  if (path == NULL)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return -1;
    }

  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}
stub_warning (chdir)

weak_alias (__chdir, chdir)
#include <stub-tag.h>
```

Comment: Ouch.  Many more layers to this onion than I anticipated.  Thanks to everyone.  Stay tuned.  More hilarity may ensue in coming weeks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you've found is a stub function for systems it's not implemented on. You need to look under the `sysdeps` tree for the actual implementation. The following may be of interest:

- `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux`
- `sysdeps/posix`
- `sysdeps/i386` (or `x86_64` or whatever your cpu arch is)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but please be sure to look at the others too, especially if you're interested in how glibc builds syscall wrappers. My answer was less targetted at your specific question (about `chdir`) but may be more useful if you want to know where/how more complex (not just a syscall wrapper) system-specific functions are implemented.

Answer (score 11):

The actual system call code for `chdir()` is auto-generated on most systems supported by `glibc`, by the script [`make-syscalls.sh`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/make-syscalls.sh;hb=HEAD).  That's why you can't find it in the source tree.

Answer (score 7):

That's a generic stub that is used if another definition doesn't exist; `weak_alias` is a `cpp` macro which tells the linker that `__chdir` should be used when `chdir` is requested, but only if no other definition is found.  (See [weak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) [symbols](http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/tag/weak-symbols/) for more details.)

`chdir` is actually a system call; there will be per-OS system call bindings in the `gibc` source tree, which will override the stub definition with a real one that calls into the kernel.  This allows `glibc` to present a stable interface across systems which may not have all of the system calls that `glibc` knows about.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the actual system calls aren't defined *anywhere* in the source tree - they're generated at build time from [syscalls.list](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/unix/syscalls.list) (linked is the one in sysdeps/unix, there are additional ones further down), a series of macros in [sysdep.h](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob?f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h) (linked linux/i386), and [a script](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/unix/make-syscalls.sh) that actually generates the source files.

Comment: without sources, on a live system,  how can I see the os api called ? is it possible to strace an application , but only the code executed into glibc ?