# Where is source code for linux kernel syscall service routines?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

My understanding of a syscall (high level) workflow is:

1. User calls libc wrapper
2. wrapper puts syscall number and arguments in the right place, registers or stack
3. wrapper executes syscall or int 0x80 instruction
4. kernel interrupt handler calls sys_xxx() service routine

If that is the case, then there should be a bunch of sys_xxx() functions in kernel source. For example, for `read()`, in kernel 2.6 code, I found [sys_read](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/fs/read_write.c#L312). However, in kernel 5.4 code, I did not find such service routine code, the only [sys_read](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/include/nolibc/nolibc.h#L1631) I found is acting like a drop in replacement for the libc wrapper. So I am confused..

A related question - the reason that kernel puts the implementation in sys_xxx() is that kernel space can also call these functions, is that correct?

Comment: [man 2 syscalls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) could be of interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kernel does indeed define a function called `sys_read` that behaves as you said.  It's just a little hard to find with searching, because it's defined through a helper macro using [token concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).  See [`fs/read_write.c` line 595](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3c2edc36a77420d8be05d656019dbc8c31535992/fs/read_write.c#L595):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(read, unsigned int, fd, char __user *, buf, size_t, count)
{
    return ksys_read(fd, buf, count);
}
```

This has the effect of:

- declaring a function named `sys_read`, [aliased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892601/what-does-the-weak-alias-function-do-and-where-is-it-defined) to `__se_sys_read`
- defining `__se_sys_read`, which apparently sign-extends any 32-bit arguments and then calls `__do_sys_read`
- defining `__do_sys_read` whose body is as shown (i.e. calling `ksys_read` which does the actual work).

You can see the definition of the `SYSCALL_DEFINEx` macros at [`include/linux/syscalls.h` line 206](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ceb307474506f888e8f16dab183405ff01dffa08/include/linux/syscalls.h#L206).

Comment: are the syscalls not defined with ```asmlinkage``` any longer?

Comment: @user3882729: If you look at `syscalls.h`, you'll see that `asmlinkage` is included in the macro definition.