# Do rand and random function the same in glibc?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I'm currenlty studying PRNG, and I found that there are two function, `rand()` and `random()`, in GNU/Linux. According to the [GNU C Library section 19.8.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/BSD-Random.html), this function, `random()`, is just for supporting BSD compatibility. Here are my questions:

1. Are these two functions identical?
2. If so, where is the source code of `random()`? (I can only find `rand()` in glibc)

I've tried to fix the seed parameter, and the order of the random number from `rand()` and `random()` are the same in my PC. So, I started to find where `rand()` and `random()` are implemented in glibc. Eventually, I can only found the implementation of `rand()`, and the prototype of `random()` in [stdlib/stdlib.h](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/stdlib.h#L401) (this is not official mirror).

I also try to find it in the linux source code, but still, there is no implementation of `random()`. Is there anything I missed?

Edit1:

(Source code of `random()` prototype)

```c
/* These are the functions that actually do things.  The `random', `srandom',
   `initstate' and `setstate' functions are those from BSD Unices.
   The `rand' and `srand' functions are required by the ANSI standard.
   We provide both interfaces to the same random number generator.  */
/* Return a random long integer between 0 and RAND_MAX inclusive.  */
extern long int random (void) __THROW;
```

Answer:
Yes, they're identically the same in glibc. The reason why they are the same is because `weak_alias (__random, random)` in [random.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/random.c#L300), which eventually use the [GNU C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) called `alias`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires two clicks to find the source in the OP provided link https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/random.c

Comment: Should I paste the source code in this post? If this is need I can paste it.

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: @0___________ Reading glibc source code is no trivial thing, so a proper answer for the less gifted coders among us (like myself) would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RuudHelderman But I do not see any questions! The source of random is in my comment. I do not see more questions here.

Comment: I want to find the source code of `random()` in glibc to check if `rand()` and `random()` are really identical as I expect.

Comment: Maybe the more interesting source is [rand.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/rand.c): `int rand(void) { return (int) __random(); }` – together with `weak_alias (__random, random)` from the other file the issue should be clear, shouldn't it?

Comment: but the source code you provide in the link is __random. Can it equal to random? I can only see it been call in `rand()` [source code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/rand.c)

Comment: Ah, you might yet be interested in the [weak alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892601/what-does-the-weak-alias-function-do-and-where-is-it-defined)! Basically they *are* the same, though the weak alias would allow for exchanging `random` with another implementation while the same for `rand` does not apply (in short here: `random` is just an alias for `__random`).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is out of my knowledge. I really  appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are currently the same in glibc. However, you should use `random()` and not `rand()`. The reason is that historically the implementation of `rand()` was *not* the same and was an extremely poor random number generator. From cppreference:

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence
> produced. In the past, some implementations of rand() have had serious
> shortcomings in the randomness, distribution and period of the
> sequence produced (in one well-known example, the low-order bit simply
> alternated between 1 and 0 between calls).

Depending on what you are compiling on, you could end up with an old, low-quality `rand()`. It's a crap shoot, so don't use it.

The one drawback is that `random()` is a POSIX function, not a standard C function. You will generally find `random()` everywhere, *except* on Windows Visual C. There you should use [`rand_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/rand-s?view=msvc-170) instead of `rand()`.

For something truly portable and consistent, you could avoid libraries entirely and include the random number generator in your code. The [PCG family of generators](https://www.pcg-random.org/index.html) provide very high-quality random numbers, better than even some modern library generators, and with very fast and compact code.

The C++ standard defines and requires high-quality random number generators, found in [`#include <random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). In C++, those are a very good choice for both portability and quality.

Depending on your application, most of these have issues. See https://www.pcg-random.org/other-rngs.html . Also consider how a pseudo-random generator is seeded. Most operating systems provide truly-random data that can be used for that.

Comment: You shouldn't use _either_; they are both inadequate to modern standards for (pseudo)randomness. (They cannot be updated to newer algorithms because that would change the meaning of stored seed values.)

Answer (score 0):

> Are these two functions identical?

not necessarily.  `rand()` and `random()` historically come from different sources and so, they implement unrelated code.  But it is normal that a library that implements both, uses the same algorithm as a common code.

> If so, where is the source code of random()? (I can only find rand() in glibc)

Probably it can be also there.  Check the header files for a macro definition.

Anyway, the specifications of both are different, so check the manual page as they will probably give different random sequences for the same seeds.