# Any practical example of using LLVM Alias and IFunc capabilities?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm-ir

I'm creating a front end (toy language for now and maybe forever) that emits LLVM IR directly (not via C++ library).

I looked but could not find real and practical examples of declaring and using either of the subject capabilities. The best I have to go on is the [Language Reference.](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#aliases)

Question is as stated in the title.

Comment: I'm thinking about using IFunc for mocking. Replace function implementations in some tests. But so far it does not look like a too much of a great fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find much from LLVM, but I found a more detailed explanation from the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Aliases, especially weak aliases, can be used to define default implementations of certain functions when the system headers don't define it.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515583/where-are-syscalls-located-in-glibc-source) question shows an example of its usage in the Linux glibc source.

Judging by [this](https://willnewton.name/uncategorized/using-gnu-indirect-functions/) example, ifunc could be useful for when you want to select a different version of some function optimized for certain processors.
The resolver function you write could use some OS-specific code to determine certain system characteristics (like the processor type) and return a pointer to the correct function.

Most of this is really low level stuff, so I'm 99% sure that you don't need to use them in a language front end.